# VLookup From More Than Two Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016

**This group helped me with a previous coding question; this one is more of an inquiry:**

I have the following files: LandingPage.xlsm, Data1.xlsm, Data2.xlsm, Data3.xlsm, AssignmentPage.xlsm

Individuals 1, 2, and 3 fill out questions that are randomly assigned by AssignmentPage.xlsm (that part I have taken care of).

Where I am having issue is that the Manager needs to pull specific answers from 1, 2, 3 (each coded PS.1.1, PS.2.2, TM.3.1 ... many categories) and have the answers line up with the questions on LandingPage (which are in order). Those who are assigned to each question will change with each use, so I needed to do something like a VLookup in VBA to do this. But, before I embark on that, is it even possible to pull data in such a way?

Please let me know if I can clarify any of the processes. I do not have code yet, as I wanted to determine feasibility (and maybe a hint) before attempting said code.

Many thanks for any and all help!!

(EDIT)

Below are images of an example of what it would look like
[image: Landing Page showing all the questions]

This would need to pull information from the other three Workbooks.

[image: Individual1]
Individual 1 has 5 questions from their Workbook (Data1) to send to LandingPage.

[image: Individual2]

Individual 2 has 3 questions from their Workbook (Data2) to send to LandingPage.

[image: Individual3]

In the last image, Individual 3 has 10 questions from their Workbook (Data3) to send to LandingPage. Also of note, the randomizer has overlapped questions for Individuals 1 & 3, so both answers and validations will need to populate the respective cells.

Again, I am appreciative of any hints or even just nudges in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah you should probably clarify with some screen shots or a sample file maybe using google sheets.

Comment: Thank you @pgSystemTester! I updated it with an example and some imagery; I hope that gives some clarity to my inquiry. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Check out this post regarding vlookup between 2 separate google sheets https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-between-two-separate-google-sheets/

Comment: I had never thought to look at it that way, @suchislife. Thank you! Seems obvious now. :-) ... Is there a VBA approach that might accomplish the same thing, or is that overthinking the problem?

Comment: I would append the tables to each other using Power Query. This will allow you to consolidate multiple sheets into a single table, from their you can Vlookup using the Key to pull in the answers. No VBA required.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkS.! I appreciate that approach as well.